# How to create Link button in android

Tags: android-widget

I want to create Link button in android.
Can anyone guide me in how I can create a Link button in android?

Answer (score 21):

Simple. Just put the link in your TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLink"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about_link"
    android:autoLink="all" />
```

Note: The most important property here is `android:autoLink="all"`. This allow you to link to urls, emails and phone numbers.

In your strings.xml add the link:

```
<string name="about_link"><a href='http://example.com'>http://example.com</a></string>
<string name="about_email"><a href='mailto:admin@example.com'>admin@example.com</a></string>
```

I know this answer is coming really late, but hope it helps someone else coming along.

Answer (score 3):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);
```